# How to set Array of Object in State in React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, state

I have JSON response from api in this format :

```
[{"_id": "6059ee86c0a1fd8fb7ce6d9b", "created_date": "2021-03-23T13:35:02.000Z", "isDeleted": "0", "friends": [[Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object]], "sharedEML": 0}, {"_id": "605306c1b8b11e0a467c502e", "created_date": "2021-03-18T07:52:33.000Z", "isDeleted": "0",  "friends": [[Object]], "sharedEML": 0}]
```

I want to show the data in the screen. So I am setting the complete response into the state using

```
this.setState({data : JSONdata})
```

But Getting this error:
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {isDeleted, sharedEML,  _id, friends, created_date}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

What to do. How to manage it. or can you suggest a better way to handle large data. Should I use Redux or anything else. I am new to React Native and did not used Redux before. Your suggestion might help!!

Comment: When did you caught the error while rendering the data on screen?

Comment: You're trying to render the object, you can use `JSON.stringify(this.state.data)` in the JSX to render it as a string.

Comment: @RagulCs No before rendering, when I use setState. it showing me error on setting the state

Comment: @RameshReddy I am not rendering anything right now. The error appear when I try to set the state with the data. On this.setState function

Comment: @DevPy Add the JSX to the question.

Comment: @RameshReddy I did not have anything related to JSX right now.. The simple problem as stated already that on button click I am calling a function that fetch the data from API, the response of the API is in the form shown above and then I am setting state with the response returned from API.

Comment: Then add the code for fetching. Beacuse by using fetch you have to convert json to js objects

Comment: try render() {return null} to ensure your jsx didn't related to the data